# How to set view controller inside the scrollview?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

My requirement is to set the multiple view controller in the scrollview.

Comment: You should look into [Container Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jasidepanels

Comment: @NeverHopeless : Nope i'm not Looking for sliding menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In viewController1's nib file add a scrollView as subview and make the outlet named myScrollView.And set the delegates too.Then over the scrollView add a UIView as subview and make the outlet as contentView.

create a property for your viewController named yourViewController (it should have a nib file with same name).

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) YourViewController *yourViewController;
```

in viewDidLoad of viewController1

```
self.yourViewController = [YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addChildViewController:self.yourViewController];// the viewController you are going to add.
 self.yourViewController.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
 [self.contentView addSubview:self.yourViewController.view];
 [self.yourViewController  didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Will this work out? can you pls elaborate if u dont mind

Comment: Yea.its worked for me.We can get the self.yourViewController's view in your contentView (those which u placed in ur scrollView).what u want to know in detail?

Comment: that view controller should fix the scroll view and detail code will help me out i guess.!

Comment: Oops I'm using Interface builder.!

Comment: No probs.it will work for nib too.ViewController1 with nib ViewController1.xib and YourViewController with nib YourViewController.xib

Comment: I have one more issue if i want to use multiple views hw it can be done?

Comment: Simple.add one more contentView and do the same steps.take care of scrollview contentOffset.